# Jquery alert fire two times instead of once with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am working with jquery and php, Right now i have "Edit" button but whenever
i am clicking on button i am getting "alert" twice instead of one time,
Here is my html code(inside php tag)

```
<?php
$PostComment2='<div class="button1'.$CommentID.'">
<span  name="MaxValue" value='.$CommentID.' data-val='.$CommentID.' id="MaxValue" class="edit_post_comment">
Edit2
</span></div>';
?>
```

Here is my script

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click','.edit_post_comment',function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      alert('Hello world');
      //further code...
    });
}); 
</script>
```

How can i alert one time only instead of twice,Where i am wrong ?

Comment: Your example code works as it is, it doesn't show two alerts.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Check the source code of your page, maybe you included the script block twice per accident?

Answer (score 0):

may you are using the class twice in the body? Please check. You may try using id.

Comment: Multiple elements with the same classname doesn't have an effect here, as the event was delegated to the document.